# Checking out previous commit with Github and VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch, git-commit

I accidentally made a commit that I should not have to the master of my project in GitHub. I am now trying to checkout to a previous commit using VS Code. I got the URL of that commit.  I do have the remote set up in VS Code but cannot figure out how to do this.

My thought was to go to checkout to and enter the URL of the commit. Then I would switch to the master branch and commit this.  But that gives me an error `"Can't push refs to remote"`.

Comment: It's hard to help with git issues without a clearer picture of what you want and what has happened so far.

Comment: I'm trying to revert to a previous commit on the master branch.

Comment: "Revert" has a specialized meaning in git. Do you actually mean "reset"?

Comment: Do you want to undo a commit (revert), or act like it's never been done?

Comment: Sorry, I realize I phrased that wrong.  My working copy is correct.  My remote copy has a commit that is totally wrong because a different project got committed to the repository.  So, I need to undo a commit

Answer (score 2):

1- Open the terminal in your VS (make sure terminal openned in your project)

2- write :

```
$ git log
```

It will show you list of recent commits copy the the commit ID you want to back to it.
(Any commit above will be reset)

```
$ git reset [commitID]
```

Now you have your changes not committed.

You can checkout now to the branch your work is in and stage your changes and commit them.

---

If the issue is in your remote (as you mentioned in comments).

There is more than one way.
First sync your local with you remote
Then the same approach with the git log to get the commit id.
Use git revert to fix your unwanted commit

```
$ git revert [commitID]
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Removing a commit from the history on a remote is not easy; it doesn't want to let you do it. On the branch where the problem is, working on your machine, you can `fetch`, then `pull`, then `reset --hard` back to before the unwanted commit, then `push` — but you will have to push with force, to get past the remote's reluctance to let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question by searching for checking out a previous commit within VSCode If you want to do this within vscode there is a good extensions for this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory

under "more" in the commit list (see below screenshot) you can checkout a specific commit

[image]